# sh error for long command passed from make.exe on cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I have a makefile with a long shell command and when I run make the shell gives the following error 
`/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

I'm using the mingw make.exe v3.82 instead of the one shipped with cygwin.

Any idea?

a mimic of the Makefile code with similar number of characters:

```
_trial :
    @sleep 10;if [ "sgggffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz aaaaaaaaaaaaaa" != "sgggffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz aaaaaaaaaaaaaa" ]; then\
    echo "sgggffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz aaaaaaaaaaaaaa";\
    echo "sgggffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz aaaaaaaaaaaaaa";\
    echo "sgggffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddffffffff aa";\
    fi
```

Comment: Almost certainly your recipe is not valid shell syntax.  However, since you don't actually show us any useful info, we can't help.

Comment: @MadScientist I added the command causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me on Linux, so it must be a Windows issue.  I know for a fact that Windows has a much smaller limit on the size of command lines than most UNIX systems so that could be part of the problem.

Did I understand you right, that you're trying to run the mingw32 version of make inside a cygwin shell?  That will not work, I don't think.  I'm far from knowledgeable about Windows but I'm pretty sure you have to use cygwin tools inside cygwin, and you can't use cygwin tools outside of cygwin.

I recommend you ask your question (as well as providing all pertinent details such as the exact version of GNU make, how it was compiled, cygwin environment, etc.) on the make-w32@gnu.org mailing list: folks who know a lot about running GNU make on Windows of all stripes tend to hang out there.

Sorry for the less-than-helpful answer :-/